# calling a class below of another class

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, python-class

I'm working on a django project with rest_framework and I have a problem with serializers. Here is my code:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    featured_product = ProductSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = [
            'title',
            'featured_product',
        ]

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = CategorySerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'title',
            'price',
            'category',
        ]
```

as you see, at `ProductSerializer` Im using `CategorySerializer`, and also at `CategorySerializer` I need to use `ProductSerializer`. if I run the code I get `NameError: name 'ProductSerializer' is not defined`. 
 **First try:**
I tried to write them in two different files and import them at top of both files but I got `Circular Import` error
**Second try:**
I defined an empty class with name of `ProductSerializer` class at the top of my code but it didn't worked.

Comment: You could assign `featured_product` and `category` to these classes after you have defined both of them.

Comment: After your `class ProductSerializer` statement, just do `CategorySerializer.featured_product = ProductSerializer(read_only=True)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you accomplish what you are looking for, it will end in an infinite serializer process: `CategorySerializer` -> `.featured_product` -> `ProductSerializer` -> `.category` -> `CategorySerializer` -> `.featured_product` -> `ProductSerializer` -> ...

To avoid that is better to create additional serializers, for example:

```py
class ProductListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'title',
            'price',
        ]


class CategoryListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = [
            'title',
        ]


class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    featured_product = ProductListSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = [
            'title',
            'featured_product',
        ]


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = CategoryListSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'title',
            'price',
            'category',
        ]
```

But if you really want to have that circular relationship, you can do it using `SerializerMethodField`, for example:

```py
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    featured_product = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = [
            'title',
            'featured_product',
        ]

    def get_featured_product(self, obj):
        return ProductSerializer(obj.featured_product).data


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = CategorySerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'title',
            'price',
            'category',
        ]
```

Comment: 2nd ways worked for me in Django 4.0 